# Multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have read that it is not possible to define multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\ge 3$ in any manner whatsoever so that together with usual addition it forms a field. However I have not been able to read a proof of this. Can someone give me a proof or a reference to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true: For every $n \geq 1$ there is an isomorphism of abelian groups $(\mathbb{R}^n,+) \cong (\mathbb{R},+)$ (compare dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$), and the latter carries the usual field structure.

However, it is true when you require that the multiplication is compatible with the usual vector space structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. In other words, every finite field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ has degree $1$ or $2$. This is because they can be embedded in the algebraic closure $\mathbb{C}$ of $\mathbb{R}$, which has degree $2$.

In the non-commutative and non-associative case, there is a famous result proven by means of topological K-theory that there is no division algebra structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ except for $n=1,2,4,8$ (see for example [Allen Hatcher's notes](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) on K-theory, Theorem 2.16). The division algebras of these dimensions are $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H},\mathbb{O}$.

Comment: I was about to ask you for a reference when you added it, +1.

Comment: How do you know that $\mathbb R^n$ with the supposed field structure is a field extension of $\mathbb R$ (with the usual field structure)?

Comment: Thank you. Now it should be - finally - correct.

Comment: Note that it is mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra#Not_necessarily_associative_division_algebras) that "there are infinitely many other non-isomorphic commutative, non-associative, finite-dimensional real divisional algebras, but they all have dimension 2". I suppose that apart from the complex numbers, none of these algebras have a unit element.