# Multiplication and the vector space $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is it possible to define multiplication of two vectors in the vector space $\mathbb R^n$ such that the cancellation laws hold?

Of course, for $n=1,2$ (real numbers and complex numbers) it is possible, but I am asking for the general case.

Related: [Multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316521/multiplication-in-mathbbrn)

Comment: What about the quaternion product? It does work.

Comment: @Bye_World Did you see the link posted above? Is it correct to say that except for n=1,2,4,8 no multiplication can be defined to satisfy the cancellation laws?

Comment: @qman By cancellation laws I mean $ax=ay$ implies $x=y$ where $a\ne 0$ (and similarly right cancellation). I am not excluding zero divisors.

Comment: @qman: Could you please expand this a bit and post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer will depend on what other properties you wish the vector space to have.

By [Frobenius's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)), there exist exactly $3$ finite-dimensional unital associative division algebras$^\dagger$ over the reals up to isomorphism.  These correspond to the real numbers $\Bbb R$, complex number $\Bbb C$, and the quaternions $\Bbb H$.  The quaternions are not commutative.

By [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28composition_algebras%29), if we remove the associative property, there exist such algebras only for $n=1,2,4,8$.  These correspond to real numbers $\Bbb R$, complex numbers $\Bbb C$, quaternions $\Bbb H$ and octonions $\Bbb O$.  The quaternions are not commutative, and the octonions are additionally not associative.

If the constraint of cancellation is relaxed to not require cancellation of [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) generally rather than only the zero vector, then real [Clifford algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) exist for every $n=2^m$, with $m$ a nonnegative integer that fit the bill (with every element of the algebra treated as a vector, not only the generating vector space).

If the constraint of bilinearity in the base field is dropped (i.e. we don't require the vector space to be algebra), there will potentially be other possible products.  Though without bilinearity they will be of limited use.

---

<sup>$\dagger$: An [algebra over a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field) is essentially a vector space equipped with a product that is bilinear in the underlying field.  A [division algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) is simply an algebra which admits division.</sup>

Comment: @Bye_World - I'm still not happy with the way that the question is put.  A general answer is too convoluted.  It should at least specify distributivity and all nonzero elements being two-sided cancellative (the latter as is the stated intent).  Stronger than distributivity is $\Bbb R$-bilinearity, which could be the intent and we'd only be answering that case anyway.  Cancellativity is also not equivalent to division (it does not imply a multiplicative inverse nor an identity element).

Comment: I agree that ideally the question should be more specific, but we shouldn't really have control over that.  The question is OP's decision.  Your answer to it is your decision.  I think this is a perfectly reasonable answer to OP's question in this case.

Comment: We've made a slew of special case assumptions to be able to give something specific.  So we've only answered a little bit of it.  But so be it.